# ArcMap Graduated symbols: Color and size

Tags: arcmap, symbology

Is there a way to get graduated symbols with two quantities being shown?
I am making a map with bus stops where I need to show two quantities both of which are continuous.
 - Symbol size: For population served
 - Symbol Color: For mean distance in the voronoi map

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using ArcMap, you may try the following steps:

- In the *Layer Properties* dialog box, use *graduated colors* using the attribute value related to 'mean distance.'
- In the lower right corner of the main pane (in the middle), find and click on the tab named *Advanced*.
- Clicking on *Size...* brings a small dialog box in which you may be able to select the name of the attribute whose quantitative value you want to symbolize concurrently with the above step. In your case, you may select the value related to the 'population' value you are trying to symbolize.
  You may also need to try experimenting to control the size of your symbols by selecting *expression* and build your own expressions by clicking the calculator icon in this same dialog box.